# Create nested list from class C#

Tags: c#

I want create permission nested list like a treeView and create a class like this which has two subclass:

```
 public class Stuff
    {
        public const string _ = "Stuff.";
        public class Invoice
        {
            public const string __ = _ + "Invoice.";
            public const string Add = __ + "Add";
            public const string Edit = __ + "Edit";

        }
        public class Warehouse
        {
            public const string __ = _ + "Warehouse.";
            public const string List = __ + "List";
        }
    }
```

and now want something like this(TreeView or just an output doesn't matter):

```
Stuff
  |Invoice
      -Add
      -Edit
  |Warehouse
      -List
```

how can i do this?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov sorry didn't get it, you mean a list of methods for each class?

Comment: @shingo TreeView or just an output doesn't matter

Comment: `typeof(Stuff)` is already such kind of thing, eg use `typeof(Stuff).GetNestedTypes()` you can get `Invoice` and `Warehouse`. and use `typeof(Invoice).GetFields()` to get `__, Add, Edit`...

Comment: Check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dae1c72a-dd28-4232-9aa4-5b38705c0a97/populate-a-tree-view-in-c?forum=winforms)

Comment: @shingo, it works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
           Recoursive(typeof(Permissions).GetNestedTypes());
           Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static void Recoursive(Type[] type)
    {

            foreach (var c in type)
            {
                Recoursive(c.GetNestedTypes());
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
                foreach (var f in c.GetFields())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t-" + f.Name + ":" + f.GetValue(f));
                }
            }
    }
```

Thanks @shingo